# How to retrieve columns data which are distinct

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to retrieve columns of data which are having distinct values

For Ex:

```
Location FoodType Gender Alive
India    Veg      M      Y
India    NonVeg   M      N
```

I need a query to list rows of data which are having distinct values
Expected Output Is:

```
FoodType Alive
Veg      Y
NonVeg   N
```

**Distinct** and **Unique** may not work as i dont know what column will have distinct values.

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. Put one of the tags back, the one for the dbms actually used here.

Comment: You can use distinct on multiple columns

Comment: What should your query return for more than two input rows? What should it return if these rows are pair-wise different, but altogether, you have duplicates for each column value? And (as mentioned by @jarlh): The solution will depend heavily on the RDBMS you're using, so use the appropriate tag.

Comment: Add some more sample data, and adjust the result accordingly. You'll probably need a stored procedure with dynamic SQL.

Comment: It needs to be compared from two rows only.

Comment: In my application, there are two similar stores with varying field value. I just wanted to list what columns and their corresponding values to be listed out.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a list then you could use `unpivot`, count distinct values, and optionally aggregate them together with `listagg()`:

```
with t(Location, FoodType, Gender, Alive) as (
    select 'India', 'Veg',    'M', 'Y' from dual union all
    select 'India', 'NonVeg', 'M', 'N' from dual )

-- end of test data, the exact query starts here:

select col, listagg(val, ', ') within group (order by val) list
  from (
    select col, val, count(distinct val) over (partition by col) cnt
      from t
      unpivot (val for col in (Location, FoodType, Gender, Alive)))
  where cnt > 1
  group by col
```

We have this:

```
COL       LIST
--------  -------------
ALIVE     N, Y
FOODTYPE  NonVeg, Veg
```

If you insist on output in separate columns You need dynamic SQL to produce list of non distinct columns to `pivot` data again.

If there are null values in table and non nulls and you want to show such pairs use unpivot with `include nulls` and then `nvl()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

A SQL query has a fixed set of columns.  You cannot specify a query that has a variable number -- although you can do so using dynamic SQL.

You could get a list of distinct values within columns:

```
select count(distinct Location),
       count(distinct FoodType),
       count(distinct Gender),
       count(distinct Alive)
from t;
```

However, this doesn't return the values in the columns.

Comment: i will be needing a better query as my actual requirement have 30 columns of data. I am hoping mentioning all these 30 column names is not a good idea. Is there any better alternative. I am just asking i dont have any idea of such options.